# Attaching IAM Managed Policy to IAM user using Pulumi not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, pulumi

I'm using pulumi to attach an IAM Managed user policy to an IAM user, with the code snippet below.

```js
const dynamoDbUser = new aws.iam.User(`${environment.env}-dynamo-fullaccess`, {});

new aws.iam.UserPolicyAttachment("dynamo-policy", {
        policyArn: aws.iam.AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess,
        user: dynamoDbUser.name,
    });
```

When I run `pulumi up`, I see the IAM user created in the AWS console, but there are no permissions attached. Am I missing something in order to attach the policy? The policy ARN I'm trying to attach is `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess`

Answer (score -2):

`policyArn: aws.iam.ManagedPolicies.AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess`

Is the correct way to attach the policy Arn. Pulumi should really update their [documentation](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/guides/crosswalk/aws/iam/).